# Iterating through each Enum value needs to be parallelized

Tags: c#, .net, enums, task-parallel-library

What am I doing wrong in the parallel call?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TasteAll<HotCupOf>(TurnCoffeeVenMachineOn);
}

public static void TasteAll<Mode>(Action<Mode> Make)
{
    foreach (Mode mode in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Mode)))
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Make(mode) );
        //Make(mode); //<-- Works Fine with normal call
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}

enum HotCupOf
{
    Black,
    Latte,
    Cappuccino,
    Mocha,
    Americano,
    Espresso,
    Chocolate,
    Tea
}

public static void TurnCoffeeVenMachineOn(HotCupOf SelectedDrink)
{
    Console.WriteLine(SelectedDrink);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've closed over a loop variable. Each Task you are starting has a reference to the same closed over variable, which is changing as you iterate the collection.

You need something like this:

```
public static void TasteAll<Mode>(Action<Mode> Make)
{
        foreach (Mode mode in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Mode)))
        {
            Mode localMode = mode;
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Make(localMode) );
            //Make(mode); //<-- Works Fine with normal call
        }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

With C# 5, loop variables are now semantically inside of the loop block, so this is unnecessary. See Eric Lippert's [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx) for additional discussion.

Comment: thanks , first link you gave , i have visited and tried:
`Mode CurrMode = mode;` then `Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Make(CurrMode) );`

Answer (score 3):

An example:

```
    enum Gender{
        male,
        female
    }        

    Parallel.ForEach((Gender[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(Gender)), gender=>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(gender.ToString()) // example: code goes here
                });
```

Meaning:
For each Gender gender, execute code between { } asynchronously.

Comment: A description of the code would enhance this answer. Also: How does it differ from the existing answers?

Comment: @JanesAbouChleih: I took the code from Mike de Klerk's answer to davenewza's post. What he said was for me the best answer in its cleanest form. I thought it deserved an answer of its own also for my own reference for interating in parallel over an enum.

Comment: @JanesAbouChleih: I added an example

Answer (score 1):

If you want the loop to block you could also consider using `Parallel.ForEach` for this problem.  It uses a Partitioner to distribute your collection into work items and then executes them way more efficiently than if you create a new `Task` for each iteration.  This is really does depend on how heavy your `Make` calls are and also the more iterations the better.

```
public static void TasteAll<Mode>(Action<Mode> Make)
{
        Parallel.ForEach(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Mode)), mode =>
        {
            Mode localMode = mode;
            Make(mode);
        });

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Mode))` should be `Parallel.ForEach((Mode[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(Mode))`. Then you do not have to `Mode localMode = mode;` as the type is already defined for `mode`.

Comment: Thanks "Mike de Klerk" for "(Mode[])" - ich was exactly searching for this!